# Having 2 or more main() methods in C with Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

I am developing a small client / server application in C. At the moment I was calling gcc by hand and using my own make files. I had two `main()` functions, one in `server.c` and other in `client.c`.

I imported all the files I had in my project's folder into Eclipse, but when trying to compile it warned me that I had multiple definitions of main. I understand that a given executable should have a single `main()` function, but in this case I'd like to have 2, so I can run the server and the client, being that they share almost all the other `.c` files.

How to solve this? The only idea that comes to mind is to separate this in 2 (maybe 3?) projects? I'll want to run both the server and the client concurrently and I'd like to do so (if possible) through Eclipse itself.

Thanks

Edit:

makefile:

```
table-client: client-lib.o
    gcc -o tabela-client table_client.c table.c base64.c list.c client-lib.o

table-server:
    gcc -o tabela-server table_server.c message.c base64.c entry.c data.c table_skel.c table.c list.c

client-lib.o:
    gcc -c remote_table.c network_client.c message.c data.c entry.c
    ld -r data.o entry.o message.o network_client.o remote_table.o -o client-lib.o

clean:
    rm -f tabela-server
    rm -f tabela-client
    rm -f *.o
```

Comment: What does your `Makefile` look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building multiple binaries within one Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424795/building-multiple-binaries-within-one-eclipse-project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you better to split your project. And may be it's better to make 3 different projects: server, client, shared library for common functions.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting it up in three projects (server, client and common code in a library) is a good idea. Set the server and client projects up so they depend on the common code library. The common code library can be made as a static library.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up so that specific files are included/excluded from a build. By setting up a client build and server build, you can have multiple mains as long as they are kept in separate files and builds.

EDIT: Nevermind, the answer [Having 2 or more main() methods in C with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120156/having-2-or-more-main-methods-in-c-with-eclipse/8120258#8120258) is better from a maintainability perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys we can actually do it like this. I faced the same problem and able to resolve it as follows : Thankyou!

```
#define my main() 
my() 

{ 

printf("hello frnz"); 

}
```

So we can have as many mains as we wish. Vola!