# Creation and configuration of multiple executables under one project in eclipse

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Is it possible to create multiple executable files under one project in eclipse?

How do I run each individual executable?

Comment: what do you mean by files? what type of files? and a project in eclipse can obviosly have many c files. Did you try to do it and it didn't work?

Comment: file in the sense , a c program..i tried and i am able to create only one file under a project name

Comment: Are you creating them under `projectName/src` folder?

Comment: hmm.......yes..

Comment: does this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424795/building-multiple-binaries-within-one-eclipse-project) help ?

Comment: i am not clear whether i can create or not..if yes then i wil try

Comment: i tried creating two files but it is showing some error messages

Comment: Kindly put the error messages in the question with any helpful code.

Comment: Let's clear up the terminology. A program is a single **executable**. The executable may be built from multiple **source** files. Are you asking how to have several different executables configured in a project, or how to add source files?

Comment: how to have several different executables configured in a project

Comment: I edited your question to better reflect what you are actually asking. You can rollback the changes if it's wrong in any way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building multiple binaries within one Eclipse project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424795/building-multiple-binaries-within-one-eclipse-project)